# Python does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z.%f'

Tags: python

I tried to convert string into a datetime object in Python, and I can't find anything wrong with my format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z.%f`.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-11-19T17:22:23.171833', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z.%f')


  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
```

ValueError: time data '2019-11-19T17:22:23.171833' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z.%f'

Comment: Consider removing the unnecessary time zone directive and leave out:
`datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-11-19T17:22:23.171833', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')`

Answer (score 2):

Your format should be:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like isoformat, so consider to use the special case [convenience](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2019-11-19T17:22:23.171833')
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 19, 17, 22, 23, 171833)
```

Answer (score 0):

%Z - Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).

Should this be included?